# "Loading symbols for..." message after exiting debug in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a small WPF app, and every time I exit debug session, after a couple of seconds I get this message.

[image: 1]

[image]

It's extremely annoying and distracting. What's this and how can I get rid of it?

I also use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm and SimpleInjector nugets if that matters.

Comment: Do you have "Just my code" disabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022#BKMK_Enable_or_disable_Just_My_Code

Comment: Right now it's enabled. I tried both enabling and disabling it, loading window still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Tools => Options => Debugging => Symbols
2. Try to cancel the hook Microsoft Symbol Servers and Nuget.org Symbol Servers
3. Click Empty Symbol Cache

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't help

Comment: @giveall Hello, please provide the steps to reproduce this issue